# How to implement multiple sort on JSF dataTable based on map value

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to sort a list which is accessible via map structure (in its value) like this:

```
<ui:param name="currentKey" value="..." />
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.map[currentKey].currentList}" sortMode="multiple">
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

and corresponding bean

```
class Bean {
    HashMap<Object, MyDataModel> map; // + getter
}

class MyDataModel {
    List<Object> currentList; // + getter
}
```

But I get the exception with the description:

> Multiple selection reference must be an Array or a List for datatable

How should the `currentList` property be accessed in order for `sortMode="multiple"` to work?

Note: I have also tried a simple version with `HashMap<Object, List<Object>> map` and the xhtml code like `value="#{bean.map[currentKey]}"` and got the same exception.

- JSF 2
- Primefaces 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

For this specific case, in which the list value of the `p:dataTable` is stored in a map structure, I needed to distinguish the sort for each table (`private HashMap<Object, ArrayList<SortMeta>> objectSortMapping;` declared in my backing bean).

The solution came to be defining a `List<MetaSort>` for each list (in `map`) in the backing bean - with reference to the `UIColumn`s of preference to sort.

```
ArrayList<SortMeta> sortMeta = new ArrayList<>();
UIComponent viewRoot = getFacesContext().getViewRoot();
UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent(":idPathTo:column1");

SortMeta sortMetaColumn = new SortMeta();
sortMetaColumn.setSortBy((UIColumn) component);
sortMetaColumn.setSortOrder(SortOrder.ASCENDING);
sortMetaColumn.setSortField("column1");
sortMeta.add(sortMetaColumn);
```

The xhtml looks like

```
<ui:param name="currentKey" value="..." />
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.map[currentKey].currentList}" var="item"
             sortMode="multiple"
             sortBy="#{bean.objectSortMapping[currentKey]}">
    <p:column id="column1" sortBy="#{item.property}">
        ...
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Hope this helps someone.